# Google Chrome turns black for 1 second and displays all of my clips (iframes) with a shade of green when using the twitch api

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, twitch

The website retrieves 12 clips from twitch using php, it displays them all in iframes. When I just display 4 it works but 12 causes some serious issues. It works on firefox but also needs to work on google chrome. As I am just echoing the iframes I don't have much control over them.

I've posted on the twitch dev forum and 2 of the console errors are normal and should not cause any issues these errors are:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 
'Window': Invalid target origin
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```

I get these when displaying 4 clips and there's no problems.

What I think might be causing the problem is this message(I get 12 of them):

```
Deprecation] chrome.loadTimes() is deprecated, instead use standardized API: Paint Timing. <URL>
```

and then at the very end I get this message:

```
[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 85ms
```

Thank you for reading and any input is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is PHP related. Are you able to give us an HTML file (without the PHP) where these 12 clips are loaded and we can reproduce the error? jsfiddle or pastebin should work well.

Comment: @DanFromGermany It's very difficult to reproduce but I've set up an example that you can view I'll also update the post with the link: http://mytwitchclips.com/test/

Comment: I see no glitches on this page using Chrome :-/ Everything looks good and intact.

Comment: @DanFromGermany click view more than wait 1 or 2 seconds and it should glitch.  I'm using latest version of Chrome on windows.

Comment: Disable hardware acceleration in chrome.

Comment: @szatmary This fixed the errors, thank you. Do you know why hardware acceleration causes this issue? also do you know if there's a way to not use hardware acceleration for users that might have it enabled?

Comment: Because your video card can not run that many decodes at the same time. And no, it’s a browse setting, you can change it from html. The user must do it themselves.

Comment: @szatmary thank you. I owe you one. I'll have to only display 4 and load in the others separately for anyone else reading this that may be experiencing the same issues.